# using reduce on a nested object

Tags: javascript, reduce

some one gave me this question as a practice problem. I have to use "_.reduce" on the following object to print out the text "a good practice". Quite frankly I am struggling even to visualize this in my head. Any help would be appreciated.

`var test = {a:'a',b:{a:'good',c:{c:'practice'}}}`

Thank You!

Comment: Welcome to SO - we're here to help, not do homework.  Try to write the solution yourself first, then come back when you get stuck on a specific question.

Comment: its not my homework nor is it for any class or challenge. It was simply a practice problem that my friend gave me. And I did tackle it for 48 hours. when everything else failed I head here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't know how nested the object is, you'll need to use recursion to accomplish the task at hand. You can't use `.reduce` on the object itself, so you'll have to use `Object.keys` to get an array of properties from the object. Then you can `.reduce` the returned array.

```js
var test = {a:'a',b:{a:'good',c:{c:'practice'}}};
var deeperTest = {a:'a',b:{a:'deeper',b:{a:'test',b:{a:'than',b:{a:'before'}}}}};

function reducer(obj) {
  if (typeof obj != 'object') return ''; //we only want to reduce 'objects'
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    if (typeof obj[curr] != 'string')
      prev += ' ' + reducer(obj[curr]); //probably an object - let's dig in
    else
      prev += ' ' + obj[curr]; //just a string - append to accumulator
    return prev;
  }, "");  
}

console.log(reducer(test));
console.log(reducer(deeperTest));
```